# AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'get_roc_curve'

Tags: python, function, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I use my code below to import utils function :

```
import utils
```

and use this field to get the area under curve:

```
auc_rocs = utils.get_roc_curve(labels, predicted_vals, test_generator)
```

to plot my rocs as seen In the previous step.

but it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'get_roc_curve'
```

what should I do?

the code is from a project to detect diabetes from eye retina PSD image
is there any functions that I should add here?

I will be thankful if provided

my utils.py file contains :

#%%
import colorsys
from os import replace
import random

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import skimage.draw as drw


    def _fix_df(df):
        """Prepare the Data Frame to be readable
        """
        df_new = df.drop(['ID'], axis=0)
        df_new.columns = df_new.iloc[0,:]
        df_new.drop([np.nan], axis=0, inplace=True)
        df_new.columns.name = 'ID'
        return df_new
        
    
    #%% 
    # contour_to_mask() and apply_mask() functions taken from https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
    def contour_to_mask(cont, img_shape, abs_path='../'):
        """Return mask given a contour and the shape of image
        """
        c = np.loadtxt(abs_path + "ExpertsSegmentations/Contours/" + cont)
        mask = np.zeros(img_shape[:-1], dtype=np.uint8)
        rr, cc = drw.polygon(c[:,1], c[:,0])
        mask[rr, cc] = 1
        return mask
    
    def apply_mask(image, mask, color, alpha=0.5):
        """Apply the given mask to the image.
        """
        for c in range(3):
            image[:, :, c] = np.where(mask == 1,
                                      image[:, :, c] *
                                      (1 - alpha) + alpha * color[c] * 255,
                                      image[:, :, c])
        return image
    
    
    # %%
    
    def read_clinical_data(abs_path='../'):
        """Return excel data as pandas Data Frame
        """
        df_od = pd.read_excel(abs_path + 'ClinicalData/patient_data_od.xlsx', index_col=[0])
        df_os = pd.read_excel(abs_path + 'ClinicalData/patient_data_os.xlsx', index_col=[0])
        return _fix_df(df=df_od), _fix_df(df=df_os)
    
    def get_diagnosis(abs_path='../'):
        """Return three arrays of shape 488 with the diagnosis tag, eye ID (od, os)
        and patient ID
        """
        df_od, df_os = read_clinical_data(abs_path=abs_path)
            
        index_od = np.ones(df_od.iloc[:,2].values.shape, dtype=np.int8)
        index_os = np.zeros(df_os.iloc[:,2].values.shape, dtype=np.int8)
    
        eyeID = np.array(list(zip(index_od, index_os))).reshape(-1)
        tag = np.array(list(zip(df_od.iloc[:,2].values, df_os.iloc[:,2].values))).reshape(-1)
        patID = np.array([[int(i.replace('#', ''))] * 2 for i in df_od.index]).reshape(-1)
        
        return tag, eyeID, patID
```

Comment: What is the folder stucture? Is it a package? Is there an `__init__.py` in there? How do you run the "main" file?

Comment: there is a "__pycache__" file inside it I've "utils.cpython-310.pyc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `get_roc_curve` in the `utils.py` file. Currently, there is no function named `get_roc_curve` in the file that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: can you share the function formula please?

Comment: I guess you'll have to google that. I'm not into Data Science.

Comment: you can find the util.py file here at GitHub, https://github.com/vishrutskaushik/Chest-X-Ray-Medical-Diagnosis/commit/ae99a0271e31cbb5a9062fb0bb564e81c94820b6